# How to place pin numbers of dipchip of CircuiTikz outside of the package?

Tags: circuitikz

I want to design a chip with some interior gates. Putting a gate inside the chip and connecting it to a chip's pin is easy and straitforward.

[image]

- But how to move the pin numbers from inside to outside?
- How to scale the chip lines only but not the pin numbers font?
- How to align the gate output with a certain pin using the same basic length as used for pins positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard dimensions of components are chosen so that the distance between the inputs of a logic port is the same as the distance between chip pins. So you really need to scale one or another.

The safest way to scale a component is using its class options (see section 3.3 and following in the manual); the same for the line thickness. I used a global option for the thickness and a local one for the scale to show the two possibilities.

For the pin numbers, you can decide to hide them and add them manually do you can do whatever you like with them.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{
    logic ports=ieee,
    logic ports origin=center, % not needed for IEEE
    chips/thickness=4,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% when using in a node, you have to prepend "circuitikz/"
\node[dipchip, num pins=16, hide numbers, circuitikz/chips/scale=2](C){};
% put the nand port: horizontally midway between pin 6 and 7
%                    vertically in the center of the chip 
\path ($(C.bpin 6)!0.5!(C.bpin 7)$) coordinate (midway-6-7)
      (midway-6-7 -| C.north) node[nand port](N1){};
% connect pins
\draw (C.bpin 6) -| (N1.in 1);
\draw (C.bpin 7) -| (N1.in 2);
\draw (C.bpin 9) -| (N1.out);

% external numbers
\foreach \pin in {1,...,8} \node[font=\tiny, above left] at(C.bpin \pin) {\pin};
\foreach \pin in {9,...,16} \node[font=\tiny, above right] at(C.bpin \pin) {\pin};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this excellent answer!

Comment: In the meantime, I prefer a horizontal orientation of the chip. I rotated both the chip and the gate and used C.center instead of C.north. But I need three levels for the gates, at C.center but also above and below it. Using C.west places the gate at the border of the chip, one half inside and the other outside. Is there a relative positioning between C.center and C.west? C.nw or C.sw does not help.

Comment: @Uwe, please create a new question with an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) --- I really can't understand what you problem is. Notice that it is important to check and understand `calc` and perpendicular coordinates from Ti*k*Z to be able to be fluent in `circuitikz`...

Comment: BTW,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers