# How to align the gates placed within a chip using CircuiTikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I placed some gates in a chip. See my last [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584259/how-to-place-pin-numbers-of-dipchip-of-circuitikz-outside-of-the-package).

[image]

The gate N4 was aligned to pin 12 by :

```
\path (C.center -| C.bpin 12) node[and port, rotate=90](N4){N4};
```

N4 is centered vertically by `C.center`

But I need the gates N5 and N6 too, they should be placed below or above N7. But N5 should be aligned to pin 10 and gate N6 to pin 6. N7 should be aligned to both N5 and N6.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{
    logic ports=ieee,
    logic ports origin=center, % not needed for IEEE
    chips/thickness=4,
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 
 % when using in a node, you have to prepend "circuitikz/"
 \node[dipchip, num pins=16, hide numbers, rotate=90, circuitikz/chips/scale=5](C){};

 \path (C.center -| C.bpin 12) node[and port, rotate=90](N4){N4}; %%% gate N4
 \draw (C.bpin 12) |- (N4.out);

 \path (6,2.5) node[nand port, rotate=90](N5){N5}; %%% gate N5
 \draw (C.bpin 10) |- (N5.out);

 \path (6,-2.5) node[nor port, rotate=90](N6){N6}; %%% gate N6
 \draw (C.bpin 6) |- (N6.in 1);

 \path (C.center -| C.bpin 10) node[not port, rotate=90](N7){N7}; %%% gate N7
 \draw (N7.in) |- (N6.out);
 \draw (N7.out) |- (N5.in 2);

 % external numbers
 \foreach \pin in {1,...,8} \node[font=\LARGE, below left] at(C.bpin \pin) {\pin};
 \foreach \pin in {9,...,16} \node[font=\LARGE, above left] at(C.bpin    \pin) {\pin};

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

How may I align gate N6 to pin 6 without centering it vertically?

I need three different levels, the low level for N6, the medium level for N7 and the high level for N5.

Comment: it would be helpful to give the complete picture  rather than in bits -- i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is not clear to me what do you mean with "aligned". Do you mean that the center of the port is vertically above the pin? That the pin to be connected is vertically above to the input pin of the port?

Anyway, you can create whichever number of alignment "rows" you need. For example,

```latex
\path ($(C.north east)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-up);
\path ($(C.north west)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-down);
```

will create two (invisible) coordinate points in the upper part of the (non-rotated) chip, one midway from north and north east and the other simmetrically on the other side.

So:

```latex
documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{
    logic ports=ieee,
    logic ports origin=center, % not needed for IEEE
    chips/thickness=4,
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 
 % when using in a node, you have to prepend "circuitikz/"
 \node[dipchip, num pins=16, hide numbers, rotate=90, circuitikz/chips/scale=5](C){};

 % create mid-up and mid-down coordinates
 % notice that the name of the coordinates do not change with rotation

 \path ($(C.north east)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-up);
 \path ($(C.north west)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-down);

 \path (C.center -| C.bpin 12) node[and port, rotate=90](N4){N4}; %%% gate N4
 \draw (C.bpin 12) |- (N4.out);

 \path (C.bpin 10 |- mid-up) node[nand port, rotate=90](N5){N5}; %%% gate N5
 \draw (C.bpin 10) |- (N5.out);

 \path (C.bpin 6 |- mid-down) node[nor port, rotate=90](N6){N6}; %%% gate N6
 \draw (C.bpin 6) |- (N6.in 1);

 \path (C.center -| C.bpin 10) node[not port, rotate=90](N7){N7}; %%% gate N7
 \draw (N7.in) |- (N6.out);
 \draw (N7.out) |- (N5.in 2);

 % external numbers
 \foreach \pin in {1,...,8} \node[font=\LARGE, below left] at(C.bpin \pin) {\pin};
 \foreach \pin in {9,...,16} \node[font=\LARGE, above left] at(C.bpin    \pin) {\pin};

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

will give you:

[image]

To show what happens, I add the coordinate lines here(1):

[image]

Now, if you want to align with the pin, for example in such a way that the input pin of N6 is aligned with the vertical of pin 6, the thing is a bit more complex, because there are no anchors for the ports located at the center but at the height of the input pins(2).

So I would add another couple of vertical levels and use them, using the `in` anchors of the logic ports (notice that in this case you also have the centers more or less centered, but that is just by chance because the width of the chip --- the height when rotated --- is now an integer multiple of the total or height, with your scale parameters).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{
    logic ports=ieee,
    logic ports origin=center, % not needed for IEEE
    chips/thickness=4,
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 
 % when using in a node, you have to prepend "circuitikz/"
 \node[dipchip, num pins=16, hide numbers, rotate=90, circuitikz/chips/scale=5](C){};

 % create mid-up and mid-down coordinates
 % notice that the name of the coordinates do not change with rotation

 \path ($(C.north east)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-up);
 \path ($(C.north west)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-down);
 \path ($(mid-up)!0.5!(C.north)$) coordinate(mid-mid-up);
 \path ($(mid-down)!0.5!(C.north west)$) coordinate(mid-mid-down);

 \path (C.center -| C.bpin 12) node[and port, rotate=90](N4){N4}; %%% gate N4
 \draw (C.bpin 12) |- (N4.out);

 \path (C.bpin 10 |- mid-mid-up) node[nand port, rotate=90, anchor=in 2](N5){N5}; %%% gate N5
 \draw (C.bpin 10) |- (N5.out);

 \path (C.bpin 6 |- mid-mid-down) node[nor port, rotate=90, anchor=in 1](N6){N6}; %%% gate N6
 \draw (C.bpin 6) |- (N6.in 1);

 \path (C.center -| C.bpin 10) node[not port, rotate=90](N7){N7}; %%% gate N7
 \draw (N7.in) |- (N6.out);
 \draw (N7.out) |- (N5.in 2);

 % external numbers
 \foreach \pin in {1,...,8} \node[font=\LARGE, below left] at(C.bpin \pin) {\pin};
 \foreach \pin in {9,...,16} \node[font=\LARGE, above left] at(C.bpin    \pin) {\pin};


% code for the cord lines:
 \def\showcoord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,
     pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\small, pin distance=0.1cm,
    pin edge={red, overlay}]45:#1}](#1){}}

    \path (C.north) \showcoord(C.north) (C.center) \showcoord(C.center);
    \draw[dashed, red]  (mid-mid-up) \showcoord(mid-mid-up) -- (mid-mid-up -| C.south);
    \draw[dashed, red]  (mid-mid-down) \showcoord(mid-mid-down) -- (mid-mid-down -| C.south);
    \draw[dashed, red]  (C.north) -- (C.north -| C.south);
    \draw[dashed, red] (C.bpin 6) \showcoord(C.bpin 6) -- (C.bpin 11);
    \path (N5.in 2) \showcoord(N5.in 2) (N6.in 1) \showcoord(N6.in 1);


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

That, without the coordinates, is this one:

[image]

So basically, it depends on what you really want.

---

Footnotes:

(1) code to show the coordinates:

```latex
\def\showcoord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,
     pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\small, pin distance=0.1cm,
    pin edge={red, overlay}]45:#1}](#1){}}

    \path (C.north) \showcoord(C.north) (C.center) \showcoord(C.center);
    \draw[dashed, red]  (mid-up) \showcoord(mid-up) -- (mid-up -| C.south);
    \draw[dashed, red]  (mid-down) \showcoord(mid-down) -- (mid-down -| C.south);
    \draw[dashed, red]  (C.north) -- (C.north -| C.south);
    \draw[dashed, red] (C.bpin 6) \showcoord(C.bpin 6) -- (C.bpin 11);
```

(2) that could be a reasonable request for enhancement, yes...

Comment: English is not my first language, it is difficult to express my feelings. I am overwhelmed. I am using stackexchange for many years now, but I never got such an excellent answer to a question of mine. You did understand well what I mean with aligned. The coordinate lines are such a brilliant idea. mid-up and mid-down is exactly that what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe! (English is my third language also, after Italian (native) and Spanish (living there)). I'm happy to have understood the problem.

Comment: Amazing and detailed answer!